# Angularjs - How to show specific div onclick a specific link and hide previous div with ng repeat- like tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Here I have 3 link,When I click a link specific div is showing,again when I click next div specific div is showing,but here I need to hide previous div onclick of next link each time.Here link and div are comes from ng repeat.For ex - when I click 'Click-1' 'name1' should show,again when I click 'Click-2' only 'name2'  should show and 'name1' should hide...so on. Here is the code below

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="maindiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in data"><span ng-click="showDetails($index,0)" class="id">Click-{{x.id}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;sssssssssssssss<span ng-show="div_[$index+'_0']" class="name">{{x.name}}</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### Script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.div_=[];
    $scope.showDetails = function(index,row){
        $scope.div_[index+'_'+row]= true;
    }
   $scope.data=
   [{
        "name": "name1",
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "name3",
        "id": "3"
    }
]
});
```

### style

```
ul li{
list-style-type:none;
cursor:pointer;
}
ul{
margin:0;
}
.maindiv{
position:relative;
}
.name{
position: absolute;
    left: 97px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 61px;
    height: 23px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is pass the item clicked to controller and store as the active item. You can use this same approach for things like `ng-class` in the links to set an active class also

Then in an  `ng-show` see if the current item is the stored active item

```js
var data = [{"name":"name1","id":"1"},{"name":"name2","id":"2"},{"name":"name3","id":"3"}];


var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.data = data;
  
  $scope.setActiveItem = function(item){
     $scope.activeItem = item;
  }
  
  // show first on page load
   $scope.activeItem = data[0];
  
});
```

```css
li { padding:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="maindiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in data" >
       <span ng-click="setActiveItem(x)" class="id">Click-{{x.id}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>  
  
  <div ng-repeat="x in data" ng-show="activeItem==x">{{x | json}}</div>  
  
</div>
```